# VBA coding that will update a website's table data after changing a form input

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, html-table, drop-down-menu

**- Details**

- I am trying to automate a data scrape from a website in Excel VBA.
- The website has a drop-down menu where you can select a location to pull data from.
- My VBA code can already grab all the data and put it into an Excel sheet.
- But I need multiple locations worth of data.
- I can change the location value input to anything I want, but the data table below doesn't refresh.

**Here is the relevant code I have as of right now:**

```
' Set the value of "location" to the inspect value needed (Atlantic is 129)
locationValue = Range("BH3").Value    'Value is 129

' Get a reference to the dropdown element
Set locationDropDown = IE.document.getElementById("location")
locationDropDown.Focus
locationDropDown.click
locationDropDown.Value = locationValue
```

**Here is the website URL:**
https://www.landus.ag/grain/futures/

**Main Problem**

- This code changes the value, but the website data below doesn't change.
- If I manually click on the drop-down while my IE is visible and select another option, the data table below refreshes. (I can't figure out how to simulate this in VBA)

**A few things I've tried**

- Website refresh
- Onclick events (although I'm not very well versed on them)

I was hoping either of these would refresh the data table below the input form.

Comment: `https://www.landus.ag/actions/landus-api-module/proxy/get-cash-bids?location=129` returns JSON which you could parse with the VBA-JSON library  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you! I was able to use Power Query Editor to parse the JSON data from the website with ease. I'm curious as to how you found the website? Thank you again. This will help immensely.

Comment: I opened the URL you provided in Chrome, opened the Chrome Developer tools (F12) on the "Network" tab, then selected a value from the drop-down list.  The request to the API showed in the Dev tools window.

Comment: @TimWilliams You're awesome! I'm excited to put this knowledge to use. Thank you.